# Remove linux file named with set of shell responsive characters

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, sh

I've created a file named \;:$"\' to test a software of mine. I ended up with an error because I cannot delete the file property. I'm trying to find a precise char combination to remove via rm, but I cannot find a way.

```
rm \\;:$\"\\\'
rm: cannot remove `\\': No such file or directory

rm "\\"\;:$\"\\\'
rm: cannot remove `\\;:$"\\\'': No such file or directory

rm '\;:$"\'''
rm: cannot remove `\\;:$"\\': No such file or directory
```

(This last try killed me)

And many many other attempts. Helping hand needed!

Comment: Just `rm \\ ` *tab* should invoke shell filename completion and produce a useful, properly escaped expansion for you.  Anyway, not a programming question.

Comment: @tripleee Try the <tab> trick. It sounds good but does not work here. Sure this is a shell programming question. What if not this?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen tab completion go wrong too often to reliably recommend it. Which is very unfortunate.

Comment: You are over-quoting. You want `rm ';:$"'\'` I believe.

Comment: I'm invoking the shell via Python. I need the whole command to run it through our SW. I'm concious this may direct me to write some kind of parser emulating the bash parser itself, but that's what we need.

Comment: @Alex If you invoke the script through python you might need to double escape everything which needs to get escaped. This because the string will get parsed in python already.. However this depends on your implementation. Can you show your python code?

Comment: Oh, if you want to try ourselves you can create the file named like that via vi /home/user/\\;:\$\"\'   Other commands won't work by writing the file name like in vi (rm \\;:\$\"\' won't work, cat \\;:\$\"\' won't work, etc).

Comment: @hek2mgl Not really relevant for the case: My python code will call a ruby client to contact a server to run a bash command to make some operations on the files. It could happen that first my python code, with a perfect bash parsing copy the files to my server, but after that moment the server takes the control and will only react to very dumb ruby calls to interact with files, which will ultimately run a bash command. I need the bash command

Comment: @tripleee Just to clearify it. Your suggest did indeed basically work. I was wondering why it didn't work in my tests. This was because there were more cryptiy files in that folder starting with `\`. This can mess up auto-completion..

Answer (score 1):

I just enter command "rm" in terminal and clicked the button "Tab" and the file is deleted:

```
roman@ubuntu:~/test12345$ ls
\;:$"\'
roman@ubuntu:~/test12345$ rm \\\;\:\$\"\\\' 
roman@ubuntu:~/test12345$ ls
roman@ubuntu:~/test12345$
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a bash solution:

```
# Create the file
touch \\\;:$\"\\\'

# Remove the file
rm \\\;:$\"\\\'
```

Let me explain: The file name is `\;:$"\'`. You need to escape every char which would be expanded in bash with a backslash and the backslash itself. Characters which would be exapanded by bash are `;`, `$`, `"` and `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

```
rm \\\;:$\"\\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work:

1. Escape everything as already suggested by other answers

   ```
   rm \\\;\:\$\"\\\'
   ```

   In fact, just typing `rm \` and then hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> should have completed the file's name for you, escapes and all.
2. Quote

   ```
   rm "\;:$\"\'"
   ```

   Note that the `"` has to be escaped since it is within double quotes. Using single quotes would avoid that but bash won't allow nested single quotes and can't escape them. So, `rm '\;:$\"\'' would fail.
3. Silly hacks. Since, presumably, you don't have many files with such strange names, you could do things like:

   ```
   rm \\*
   ```

   to delete all files whose name starts with a `\` or

   ```
   rm *\'
   ```

   to delete all files whose name ends with a `'`, etc.